# add file to queue download multi file android

Tags: android, download, retrofit

Currently I want to make a list like pictures and images on the server when I click on it, it will download the images to the memory device. If the image is downloaded, it will not download again and the image that is not there will be downloaded. Then I want to ask for a solution from everyone, how should I handle the download to be clean and good for performance. Or do you have an example for me to refer to? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to find out if your image already exists in your phone storage but the best way to find it out is by image name, compare image names before downloading.

Comment: thank you answer my question . but i need add list file realtime to download queue ? can u help me?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).